# sentinel 2A MSIL2a - transformation -

Tags: remote-sensing

I am working with Sentinel-2 satellite imagery and have downloaded a Level-2A product in the MSI2A format. I am trying to determine whether the reflectance values in this product need to be transformed, and if so, how to do so.

The reason I am unsure whether a transformation is needed is because the reflectance values I am working with are reported in large values that are not in the range of 0 to 1. when I read the data using rasterio in Python, the values are reported as large numbers, such as 2000 and 6000.

I have read online that for Sentinel-2 , surface reflectance values need to be divided by 10,000(Quantification_value) to convert the values to the expected range of 0 to 1. However, I am not sure if this is applicable to the product I am working with, or if there are other factors that I need to consider because i have information that sentinel 2A MSIL2A is already corrected for atmospheric effects and is considered to be bottom-of-atmosphere (BOA) reflectance data but why reflectance values are not within the expected range of 0 to 1 . The metadata for this product indicates a Quantification_value of 10000. Should I divide the reflectance values by this factor?

file name that i have S2A_MSIL2A_20190720T100031_N0213_R122_T32SPB_20190720T161032.SAFE

references :
[Copernicus Sentinel-2: Major Products Upgrade Upcoming - Sentinel Online 1](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/en/web/sentinel/-/copernicus-sentinel-2-major-products-upgrade-upcoming)

[Sentinel-2 Products Specification Document](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/document-library/-/asset_publisher/Wk0TKajiISaR/content/sentinel-2-level-1-to-level-1c-product-specifications?p_r_p_resetCur=false&_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR_assetEntryId=636612&_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fsentinel.esa.int%2Fweb%2Fsentinel%2Fuser-guides%2Fsentinel-2-msi%2Fdocument-library%3Fp_p_id%3Dcom_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_r_p_resetCur%3Dfalse%26_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR_assetEntryId%3D636612%26_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR_cur%3D2%26_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR_delta%3D20)

[Sentinel hub](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-2-l2a/)

edit : response : https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2a-msil2a/39214

---